# Should a question tagged with [ruby-on-rails] ever not have a [ruby] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently [~163k questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails+-ruby) with [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) but not [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby).

Should all of these have [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) added*? Should new questions have [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) added?

And what about [ruby-on-rails-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-4), should all of those questions have [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails)? ([~9k questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-4+-ruby-on-rails))

This is all assuming that the tags the questions currently have are accurate tags that are applicable to the question.

Comment: I'm  not sure if a pure ruby developer is interested in ror. As for the version tags: Other tags follow the pattern that the version tag is only used if the question is only applicable to that specific version. The generic one is used if the version doesn't matter.

Comment: Similar question on CodeReview: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6631/95296

Comment: Libraries can certainly get big enough to *never* require a language tag.  RoR is big enough, jQuery is big enough, etcetera, no point in pestering [ruby] fans with the one-and-only.  Having to re-tag 163K questions ought to be a loud enough hint.

Comment: @HansPassant So then the [~73k questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails+ruby) that have both need to have just rails? Can this be done automatically?

Comment: It cannot be done automatically.

Comment: @shelvacu No, because RoR may have questions completely unrelated to ruby. Unless there's a problem with the tag situation, I don't see what mass retagging would do anyway.