# What to do with implicit tags for a very complex, specific library?

Tags: discussion, tags

The context is a SO user who works with a coding language A, but more specifically, with library B, which is a whole tag/subject in itself because of its complexity, and it is only available for the coding language A. Just to clarify the context, if SO was a hobby forum, it would be like asking a question about baseball and tagging it with `sport`, in addition to `baseball`, just to make sure to ask it to swimmers and snowboarders who maybe never played baseball in their life.

Since library B is very complex, it would be hard to answer for someone that never learned how to use library B (i.e. all other coders of coding language A). I have seen users marking down questions that satisfied Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example criteria, but probably didn't understand the matter of the question since they never had any experience with the library.

My question would be: knowing that my question is about the library's features, not about the coding language, that marking the question would only bring clueless SO users to read the question and that tag B makes tag A completely redundant, is it okay to use only tag B?

Comment: Is it ok: Sure. Does it make sense: Depends. This will only work if there is a large enough community behind the library tag. If the library does not have that many questions, it might happen that noone reads the question in meaningful time.

Comment: related; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java

Comment: Adding [python] to [pyomo] is not wrong. Helps you by getting more views, helps contributors by learning about an obscure library.  It is all a big kumbaya.

Comment: Tagging it with the specific library already calls attention to the potential need for expertise in it, greatly lowering the chance of negative attention from users who haven't encountered it. If it's truly essential to your question, then even a cursory skim of the question will also make the dependency clear. If your question is well posed, I wouldn't worry about drive-by non-experts. I'd only worry about it if your question isn't well posed enough for them to tell they are missing some expertise.

Comment: If there is an obscure library(B) in a widely used language(A), and an answerer knows A and B, they are still likely just to search through questions tagged A, since there won't be many in B. So if you only tag it B, they won't see it.

Answer (score 30):

It is useful to tag the parent programming language.

Personally, I follow [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) (don't judge me!), but I am familiar with many libraries and concepts so if someone tags a question with just [codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter)(21.1k followers), [tcpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcpdf) (112 followers), [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) (25.5k followers), [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) (20.5k followers), etc... while omitting [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) (528.4k followers) then I will never see it.

In particular [tcpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcpdf) is a very specific and complex library so If you rely on just 112 followers then it could be ages before anyone even sees the question. Additionally, anyone following TCPDF is probably following PHP as well so it's not like the post would rise to the top of their list.

It's a disservice to your post if you decide to not harness the potential power of people that do not explicitly follow your niche tag.

---

As for:

> I have seen users marking down questions that satisfied Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example criteria, but probably didn't understand the matter of the question since they never had any experience with the library.

Yes, these types of situations do occur unfortunately so you just need to juggle the potential trade-off of limited visibility if your tag is too specialized.

When I come across a niche question that I know nothing about then I simply move along since I am certainly no expert.

There have been occasions in which I've been able to answer unfamiliar niche questions by looking at the documentation of that library, providing an example, and linking to the docs.

Comment: Same with `sql` especially. There are dozens of `sql` flavors with a lot of overlap. If people just tag `oracle` only, I'm never going to see it. But chances are good that I *could* help (or learn to help).

Comment: `There have been occasions in which I've been able to answer unfamiliar niche questions by looking at the documentation of that library, providing an example, and linking to the docs.` there is also the flipside - a beginner may tag a question with just the library without realising that a solution can be achieved without it. In that case, somebody following the parent language tag can still provide a suitable answer without having knowledge of the library.

Answer (score 4):

Use both tags. The people who are going to go "I don't know anything about this, so its not an Minimal Complete Verifiable Example and I'm going to downvote" will be just as stupid in the review queue if you only have the specialized tag not the general language one; so trying to hide it from people who only follow the main tag won't help.

Answer (score 1):

Related question: [Should a question tagged with [ruby-on-rails] ever not have a [ruby] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319247/should-a-question-tagged-with-ruby-on-rails-ever-not-have-a-ruby-tag)

There's currently 197K questions that have [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) but not [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby). Ruby is the language, Rails is the framework. There's 94K that have both, and 100K that have Ruby but not Ruby on Rails.

If it's happening that frequently, then it's probably a good sign that either it's ok to do so, or that any "wrongdoing" is not a personal failing specific to you.